# mvc 4 localization in multi layer web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I am new to MVC and am trying to get a web application up and running that will be displayed in a couple of languages.

I have the localization functioning as I want in my web project but I have split my domain model into a separate class library and am wanting to perform localization on my property attributes as in the web project.

I have created a folder in my domain model project called Resources and have a Client.resx to store my fallback/default strings for property error messages and display names etc... I have also created a Client.es.resx for Spanish errors and display names however even if my culture is set to es, as below in my Global.aspx, I receive spanish on main web views but still receive english error messages on properties etc.. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create culture info object 
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es");

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dope...... I had forgot to add the named parameters to the attribute as below...... what a clown!

```
[Required (ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ModelRes.Client))]
```